# Adjust content height dynamically to window height using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I simply want to limit 'view' div height to the window height and show a scrollbar next to the text that goes beyond the window height..  I had it working but for some reason I messed up again and don't see why..

```
<html>
<head><style>
    #view {height:100%}
    #wrap {display:flex;border:solid;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;padding:20px}
    #plan {flex: 1 1 auto;width:20%;display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
    #plan-head{}
    #plan-info{}
    #plan-list{flex 1 1 auto;overflow:auto;padding:10;background-color:#F7F7F7}
    #map {flex: 1 4 auto;overflow:hidden;border:0;width:70%;overflow-x:none; }
    #cal {flex: 1 2 auto;width:40%}
</style></head>
<body>
<div id="view">

<div id="wrap">

<div id="plan">

<div id="plan-head"style="padding:10px;background-color:#F7F7F7">Content 1</div>
<div id="plan-info">info</div>
<div id="plan-list">content that should scroll:
o Plan sfd sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf sqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsfsqf sdqf sfd sfqd s ds sdf sd sd sdsdf fqf sfqsf sf qsfqs fqs fqsf qsf fqs fqsf qsfq sdfs fs fqs d ff sfq sf sfqs fqsf sdf qsf sd qsf qsf qsf df qs fsq df f sfqsf sfs fqsf f
</div>

</div>

<div id="map">content 2</div>

<div id="cal">content 3</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I would like to see three columns, all max height of window and the first with 3 rows, of which the first two rows limited to their content and the bottom row taking up the remaining screen height with a scrollbar inside it (meaning inside the plan-list div).  Feeling a bit stupid at the moment since it's probably quite simple ;)

Comment: only a matter of inheriting heights and setting `box-sizing: border-box` - see https://jsfiddle.net/6k7aed9t/

Comment: Tx!!!  You are my hero today :)